# getjson problem. failed to load the resource

Tags: javascript, html, getjson

Here is my code on my js page

```js
$("#get-data").click(function() {
  var showData = $("#show-data");

  $.getJSON("https://data.iledefrance.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=repertoire-bibliotheques&q=&refine.typeinst=Mus%C3%A9e", function(data) {
    var records = data.results;

    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
      var musee = records[i];
      var html = '<div class="card">' + '<p>' + musee.nometablissement + '</p>' + '<p>' + musee.nomrue + '</p>' + '<p>' + musee.codepostal + '</p>' + '<p>' + musee.commune + '</p>' + '<p>' + musee.descoll + '</p>' + '</div>';
      showData.append(html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  Les musées à Paris
</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical-center">
    <button href="#" id="get-data">
      <span id="textbut">Découvrez les différents musées parisiens</span>
    </button>
    <div id="show-data"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand where I made a mistake, because the console tells me that there are 2 errors, corresponding to: failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: It seems to be saying that `records` is undefined when you are trying to access `data.records` perhaps you are traversing the json incorrectly. It is hard to help when we don't know what you are trying to do with the api data. The request itself seems to be fine.

Comment: How should I define records then? I just want the api data to appear when I click on the button named "découvrez les différents musées parisiens"

Comment: Where are the 2 errors? Which 2 things are failing to load?

Comment: 404 means the URL is incorrect.